# Android Alarm Manager plugin doesn't fire

Tags: android, flutter, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm using the android_alarm_manager package and it just doesn't fire, test1 prints but not test2, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as there is no error message, and doctor doesn't display anything unusual. I can provide extra info if necessary.

(MainPage() is my the starting page of the app)

```
void printHello() {
 print('test2');
}

main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 final int helloAlarmID = 0;
 await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
 runApp(MaterialApp(home: MainPage(),));
 await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), helloAlarmID, printHello);
 print('test1');
}
```

Comment: Avoid using periodic alarms, if targetting above api 19 use setwindow and setexact, also it depends on system dOZE and manufacturers too, chinese ROM never runs tasks, processes, alarms if that are not belonging to whatsapp / facebook or google or some known company they are whitelisted

Comment: Thanks! My phone is a huawei I'll try to use those and I'll report back.

Comment: I'm having a problem because I can't find a package that has setWindow and setExact, do you know what i should use? I can't really write java or kotlin so I can't do it by myself.

Comment: @DiinFerhatovic setWindow and setExact refers to the internal functions of the android AlarmManager class. In the flutter API you can use the parameter `exact: true` in the periodic function. If you have fixed the issue in the meantime, I would also appreciate a hint to the solution; I am lost on pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 I never found a solution to this, I used the workmanager package instead. Good Luck!